# How to import tensorflow in google colab

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

Google Colab seems throwing the below error while trying to import `Tensorflow`, while it was working okey couple of weeks ago

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
import sys
import codecs
import tensorflow as tf
from tqdm import tqdm
from chardet import detect
from keras_radam import RAdam
from keras import backend as K
from keras_bert import load_trained_model_from_checkpoint
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/__init__.py in <module>()
      4 except ImportError:
      5     raise ImportError(
----> 6         'Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. '
      7         'Install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow`')
      8 

ImportError: Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. Install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow`

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
```

**NOTE** : am running on TPU and alreadt tried `!pip install tensorflow` but reuirements are satisfaied

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this error. First of all when running your code I do not get this error, even if I add import keras afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to re-order my imports like below and used keras version `2.3.0`

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
import sys
import codecs
import tensorflow as tf

!pip install keras-bert
!pip install keras-rectified-adam

!pip install keras==2.3.0

from tqdm import tqdm
from chardet import detect
from keras_radam import RAdam
from keras import backend as K
from keras_bert import load_trained_model_from_checkpoint
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

Answer (score 0):

This should suffice i feel
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf

This has always worked for me in Google Colab. I think the issue is that you are giving %tensorflow_version as 1.x please try changing that to 2.x

Comment: same issue still exists while using 2.x

Comment: please share the portion of the code where you are invoking keras

Comment: I have added all the import statements

Comment: I dont have RAdam and keras_bert in my system but the errors dont seem to correspond to those anyways. Please try this instead `from tensorflow.keras import backend as K` . This is because in tf 2, keras is in built in the framework and we dont have to install it separately as a stand alone package

Comment: solved for the `from keras import backend as K` but not for keras_bert

Comment: i havent used bert but looks like TF2 has a bert package and you can install that using `pip install bert-for-tf2` - this is from : https://pypi.org/project/bert-for-tf2/0.3.4/ and usage is `from bert import BertModelLayer` . however not sure if that package meets your requirement though